# Possible to preserve relationship between continuous and categorical variables simulating with SPSS SIMPLAN?

Tags: simulation, spss

I'd like to simulate a dataset based on existing data using the `SIMPLAN CREATE` command in SPSS (v24). From what I can tell, existing correlations between continuous variables are automatically simulated, and relationships between categorical variables can be simulated when including the `/CONTINGENCY MULTIWAY = YES` sub-command. However, I've not been able to (easily) simulate relationships between categorical and continuous variables, say, between gender and height.

I tried cheating by computing copies of the categorical variables and setting them to scale variables in the original data before simulating:

```
COMPUTE CatScale1 = Cat1.
COMPUTE CatScale2 = Cat2.
EXECUTE.
VARIABLE LEVEL CatScale1 CatScale2 (SCALE).
```

Then plugged them into `SIMPLAN` like so:

```
SIMPLAN CREATE
  /SIMINPUT INPUT = Scale1, Scale2, Cat1, Cat2 , CatScale1(FORMAT=F,0), CatScale2(FORMAT=F,0)
  /CONTINGENCY MULTIWAY = YES
  /PLAN FILE = 'test.splan'.

SIMRUN
...
```

This automatically preserves the relationship between the two scale variables, and the relationship between the categorical variables is preserved as requested.

I then change the converted variables back to categorical in the simulated dataset:

```
COMPUTE CatScale1 = RND(CatScale1).
COMPUTE CatScale2 = RND(CatScale2).
EXECUTE.
VARIABLE LEVEL CatScale1 CatScale2 (NOMINAL).
```

Running the following gives reasonably similar results, showing that the relationship is maintained between the scale variable and the back-converted categorical variable:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE original.
MEANS TABLES = Scale1 by Cat1
  /CELLS = MEAN COUNT STDDEV.
DATASET ACTIVATE synth.
MEANS TABLES = Scale1 by CatScale1
  /CELLS = MEAN COUNT STDDEV.
```

However, swapping in `Cat1` on the `MEANS` command for the `synth` data demonstrates no differences between groups; the relationship doesn't hold up.

Checking on the relationships between the categorical variables:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE original.
CROSSTABS
  /TABLES = Cat1 by Cat2
  /CELLS = COUNT.
DATASET ACTIVATE synth.
* This is pretty close to the above, as expected.
CROSSTABS
  /TABLES = Cat1 by Cat2
  /CELLS = COUNT.
* Some of the cells were close, some were way off.
CROSSTABS
  /TABLES = Cat1 by CatScale2
  /CELLS = COUNT.
* Everything was waaayyy off.
CROSSTABS
  /TABLES = CatScale1 by CatScale2
  /CELLS = COUNT.
```

So it looks like the trick works for back-converting a categorical variable (with 2 levels, anyway) and its relationship to a scale variable, but back-converting won't maintain the relationships between the categorical variables (at least if one has 2 levels and the other has 4), which is about what I expected. The whole thing feels kludgey and is probably dangerous in a variety of circumstances. For the life of me, I can't find a better way. I'd rather not go the model input route, as I don't want to push the simulation  toward a prediction in the event users have other predictions they'd like to test.

Have I missed something?